# Can't get Zabbix to email alerts

Tags: email, ssl, amazon-ses, zabbix

I've recently spun up a new Zabbix 3.0 instance on Ubuntu 16.04 using Php 7.0 and I am running into a lot of issues trying to get it to e-mail the Zabbix administrators. We are trying to use Amazon SES to send out the e-mails. For our setup, we have a usename & password that was generated by SES we are using port 587 with SSL/TLS connection. I've made sure that the alert is enabled and that the E-mail media type was enabled as well. I've also double checked the Zabbix is compiled with SMTP & TLS support. I've also verified that the Zabbix server can get to the Amazon SMTP endpoint on port 587. From the messages it seems to be some form of a communication issue, but everything I've tried isn't really getting me anywhere.

```
SSL connect error: Encountered end of file

26163:20170515:131115.744 * NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
26163:20170515:131115.744 * Encountered end of file
26163:20170515:131115.744 * Closing connection 0
26163:20170515:131115.744 SSL connect error: Encountered end of file
26163:20170515:131115.744 End of send_email():FAIL
26163:20170515:131115.744 End of execute_action():FAIL
26163:20170515:131115.744 error sending alert ID [812]
26163:20170515:131115.744 query without transaction detected
26163:20170515:131115.744 query [txnlev:0] [update alerts set 
retries=1,error='SSL connect error: Encountered end of file' where 
alertid=812]
26163:20170515:131115.746 In execute_action(): alertid [813] mediatype [0]
26163:20170515:131115.746 In send_email() smtp_server:'email-smtp.us-east-
1.amazonaws.com' smtp_port:587 smtp_security:2 smtp_authentication:1
26163:20170515:131115.750 *   Trying 54.235.77.145...
26163:20170515:131115.752 * Connected to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
(54.235.77.145) port 587 (#0)
26163:20170515:131115.752 * WARNING: failed to load NSS PEM library 
libnsspem.so. Using OpenSSL PEM certificates will not work.
26166:20170515:131115.761 __zbx_zbx_setproctitle() title:'http poller #1 
[got 0 values in 0.000736 sec, getting values]'
26166:20170515:131115.761 In process_httptests()
26166:20170515:131115.761 query [txnlev:0] [select h.hostid,h.host,h.name,t.httptestid,t.name,t.variables,t.headers,t.agent,t.authentication,t.http_user,t.http_password,t.http_proxy,t.retries,t.ssl_cert_file,t.ssl_key_file,t.ssl_key_password,t.verify_peer,t.verify_host from httptest t,hosts h where t.hostid=h.hostid and t.nextcheck<=1494868275 and mod(t.httptestid,1)=0 and t.status=0 and h.proxy_hostid is null and h.status=0 and (h.maintenance_status=0 or h.maintenance_type=0)]
26166:20170515:131115.762 End of process_httptests()
26166:20170515:131115.762 query [txnlev:0] [select min(t.nextcheck) from httptest t,hosts h where t.hostid=h.hostid and mod(t.httptestid,1)=0 and t.status=0 and h.proxy_hostid is null and h.status=0 and (h.maintenance_status=0 or h.maintenance_type=0)]
26166:20170515:131115.762 No httptests to process in get_minnextcheck.
```

Just for reference, I do have `Zabbix` running off of `HTTPS`. To get that configured I just made a change to the Apache sites-enabled default file to point to the certificate on the local machine. They are signed certificates. I had also installed the most recent `openssl` package

Has anyone ran into this issue before or know of what might be happening?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is there anything in the logs about email after the snippet you have posted?

Comment: I grabbed some more info from the logs and edited above

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

587 is STARTTLS, use 465 for SSL/TSL (don't forget to configure security group):
[image]

You may have problems with email/email domain verification. Be sure that's OK.

Comment: Hey Jan! Thanks for the help! This actually was my exact issue. I can't believe I didn't notice the wrong port being used.